# Find the last valid block height for a given blockhash

Tags: rpc, blockhash

https://docs.solana.com/developing/clients/jsonrpc-api#getlatestblockhash provides a way to get the latest blockhash and last valid block height for a given commitment.

https://docs.solana.com/developing/clients/jsonrpc-api#isblockhashvalid provides a way to know if a given blockhash is valid.

I'm looking for a way to obtain the last valid block height for a given blockhash. Does this exist?

Edit: to add a little about the use case --

Transactions may have a recent blockhash provided by a wallet. Apps and helper libraries that have only the signature of the transaction need to know if they should continue to retry it or look for confirmation. If there was a way to determine the last valid height for a given hash, this would be easy for them.

Comment: Gunning for the ‘student’ badge, I see.

Comment: @steveluscher nooo I actually really need this!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the current state, there's no way to figure out the last valid block height for a given blockhash.

Most dapps manage this by tracking the blockhash's context in the app, but this does not help in your case where a wallet provides the blockhash without the slot context.

There's an [issue to track potential work on github](https://github.com/solana-labs/solana/issues/27189).